# destructor for queue (what's the benefit from it)

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

while i was studying queue implementation in c++ , i come on this statement

```
queue::~queue() {
    if (storage) 
        delete [] storage;
}
```

so what does if (storage) means ? , in the implementation (Storage supposed to be a dynamic array that store data .  so why we said if it is true delete storage , does it mean if the storage is full ?

Comment: It's testing if the pointer is not null.

Comment: Which isn't really necessary, since `delete` does nothing when the parameter is null.

Comment: Pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool` in c++. A `nullptr` converts to `false` and all other pointers to `true`.

Comment: so if the parameter (storage) is null or assigned to zero it means this contains nothing and isn't necessary to delete it ?

Comment: Yes. Although as mentioned before, the `delete` operator has this check built in. How much do you know about pointers?

Comment: i think i have a good knowledge in it but this statement confused me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storage` is a pointer, and a pointer is considered "true" if it's not a null pointer. So this is testing whether `storage` is not null, i.e. that storage has been allocated for the queue with `new` (presumably the pointer is initialized to a null pointer if no storage is allocated). If nothing has been allocated, there's no need to `delete` it.

This is a redundant check, though, since the same test is built into the `delete` operator itself. Some programmers like to be explicit in their code, though.

Comment: `queue::queue(int queuesize) {
 front  = rear =0;
 capacity = size=queuesize;
 count = 0;
 if (queuesize > 0)
  data = new int[queuesize];
 else
  data = 0;

}`

this the implementation of the constructor .

Comment: Is there a default value assigned to the `storage` member variable in the class declaration?

Comment: no , but as you noticed in once the constructor is called it checks whether (queue size is equal to zero or no if true so Data which's in this case is Storage assigned to zero

Comment: Huh? How is `data` the same as `storage`?

Comment: Is the variable different in the constructor than the destructor? Or is the code in the question from a different class than the comment?

Comment: in the slides data is storage , in my code i change storage to data that's it .